# QGIS & WMS/WMF S57 file format

Tags: wms, qgis-server, s-57

How can QGIS deal with the S57 file and then act as the Server of WMS or WMF?
Can anyone explain the idea?

Any suggested way to convert S57 file to the shp Format?

Comment: There appear to be two unrelated questions here, the first question centres around how to convert an S-57 vector file into a shapefile.  The second question is about to serve a WMS and I assume WFS using qgis web server.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS relies on GDAL/OGR to read/write geospatial datasets. As OGR can read S-57 datasets you can display and also convert them with QGIS ("Save as" -> ESRI Shapefile).

Take note of the file handling / limitations described in the [S-57 driver documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_s57.html):

- S-57 feature objects are translated into features. S-57 geometry objects are automatically collected and formed into geometries on the features.
- The S-57 reader depends on having two supporting files, s57objectclasses.csv, and s57attributes.csv available at runtime in order to translate features in an object class specific manner. These should be in the directory pointed to by the environment variable S57_CSV, or in the current working directory.
- S-57 update files contain information on how to update a distributed S-57 base data file. The base files normally have the extension .000 while the update files have extensions like .001, .002 and so on. The S-57 reader will normally read and apply all updates files to the in memory version of the base file on the fly. The feature data provided to the application therefore includes all the updates.

Comment: when I open an S57 file using the QGIS Desktop, it can Display the file Contents, but the OGR said : failed to open Permission denied.

Comment: and how can I saved it as esri shpefile.?